# Input type="file" не изменяет размер

Tags: html, css

Есть три блока, в блоке 2 находится `input type="file"` с таким же размером как и блок 2. Но при клике на блок 3 открывается окно выбора файлов.
http://jsfiddle.net/m3atS/

```css
.hover {
    height: 23px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 4px;
    width: 69px;
}
.edit {
    background: yellow;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: left;
}
.input {
    background: green;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: left;
}
input {
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.remove {
    background: red;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
    <div class="edit">1</div>
    <div class="input">2
        <input type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="remove" title="Удалить">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Теперь ОК.](http://jsfiddle.net/m3atS/4/)

```css
.hover {
    height: 23px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 4px;
    width: 69px;
}
.edit {
    background: yellow;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: left;
}
.input {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: left;
}
input {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.remove {
    background: red;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
    <div class="edit">1</div>
    <div class="input">2
        <input type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="remove" title="Удалить">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: разницы нет